# PHPMailer - Sending Mail Through Google SMTP Fails, TLS Issue Suspected

Tags: php, email, ssl

I am attempting to send email using Google's SMTP servers through the [PHPMailer library](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

```
 function getMailer () : PHPMailer {

    $mail = new PHPMailer;      
    $mail->isSMTP();

// Dev Values

    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Host =  "smtp.gmail.com";
    $mail->Username = "myaddress@gmail.com";
    $mail->Password = "pass";
    $mail->Port = 587;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";


return $mail;
    }
```

Script to send email:

```
 $mailer = getMailer();
$mailer->Subject = "This is the subject";
$mailer->isHTML();

$message = "<p>This is the body.</p>";
$mailer->Body = $message;

$mailer->addAddress("myemail@test.com");
$mailer->setFrom("myemail@test.com"); 

$mailer->SMTPDebug = 2;  
  if($mailer->send()) {
header("Location: success.php");
} else {
  $mailer->ErrorInfo;
 //   trigger_error("Failed to send email: process-birthday.php", E_USER_ERROR);
}
```

I am receiving some rather odd output:

```
2017-12-22 17:47:20 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP a203sm9813338oib.47 - gsmtp 2017-12-22 17:47:20 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost 2017-12-22 17:47:20 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [68.185.111.34] 250-SIZE 35882577 250-8BITMIME 250-STARTTLS 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-PIPELINING 250-CHUNKING 250 SMTPUTF8 2017-12-22 17:47:20 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS 2017-12-22 17:47:20 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS 2017-12-22 17:47:23 SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. 2017-12-22 17:47:23 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT 2017-12-22 17:47:23 SERVER -> CLIENT: MIA��O���v��~S�D���^E{�s?z��F��18`�����e�g7��/�<69���8X��:�5&��k����l��R��>���!-U�:���e��~������xu���[d{�\��6�M Ǌ"6Q��U��y�q��g���_m���S�u�������4�V��|"I�er��PAFT���Y���b)nv��4�*^6L2,��!�vV~v©�}�[���G�aus4�vf�A��;P����<�g��yxVぞ��5����_�\���8���E�[��-��^[�_Bdx��v�|87�"�q�K ���셲�-� 2017-12-22 17:47:23 SMTP ERROR: QUIT command failed: MIA��O���v��~S�D���^E{�s?z��F��18`�����e�g7��/�<69���8X��:�5&��k����l��R��>���!-U�:���e��~������xu���[d{�\��6�M Ǌ"6Q��U��y�q��g���_m���S�u�������4�V��|"I�er��PAFT���Y���b)nv��4�*^6L2,��!�vV~v©�}�[���G�aus4�vf�A��;P����<�g��yxVぞ��5����_�\���8���E�[��-��^[�_Bdx��v�|87�"�q�K ���셲�-� 2017-12-22 17:47:24 SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

I have read over the troubleshooting documents for the library. A few things I have tried:

- Switching to SSL and the port 465
- Ensuring less secure applications are enabled on my Google account
- Running `<?php echo (extension_loaded('openssl')?'SSL loaded':'SSL not loaded')."\n"; ?>` to ensure SSL was loading

The odd thing is, this configuration was working previously. I am also able to send email using the same credentials through .NET and Java apps (last I recall).

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: The output is because you have set Debug level 2.. Set it at 0. Otherwise I see nothing wrong. You use correct email addresses?

Comment: function getMailer () : PHPMailer { looks strange

Comment: Yes, the email is correct. I set debug output to 2 because it is not sending the email. I was trying to find the issue.

Comment: Could not connect. If it is not the user/password, you can try port 465 and  SSL. I use 587 and TLS without problem with googlemail.